# How to run a single file in Netbeans with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, netbeans

I ported our project to gradle.

Everything runs fine, also debug.

However, sometimes I'd like to start a specific `main` belonging to a given class, which is different from the `mainClass` specified in Gradle.

How can I achieve something like that without having to modify manually everytime `build.gradle`?

Right click -> Run still executes the gradle `mainClass`..

Answer (score 0):

What version of NetBeans are you running?
NetBeans 11.3 (with built-in Gradle support, not the external plugin), runs the selected file when you use the context menu as described.
It appears to inject a "runSingle" task into the Gradle project to accomplish this.